# Declaring array in react typescript tsx file gives "error TS1109: Expression expected"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

When I try to declare an array within a React (but using typescript) tsx file I get the error message:

> "error TS1109: Expression expected"

```
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {  var nums:number[] = [1,2,3,3]  }  // ERROR HERE
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `var nums:number[] = [1,2,3,3]` is not an *expression*. It's a statement.

An expression would be `[1,2,3,3]`.

## Easy way to think about it

Anything that can be assigned to a variable is an *expression*. You wouldn't do:

```
const foo = var nums:number[] = [1,2,3,3]; // ERROR `var nums:number[] = [1,2,3,3]` is not an expression
```

## Solution to declaring

Do it out of JSX e.g.

```
public render() {
    var nums:number[] = [1,2,3,3]
    return (
      <div>
        {  nums[0]  }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: So can one not define an array within render/return here then?

Comment: Added "solution to declaring"

Comment: @Greg, you technically can but it's generally not recommended. What is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: ok - got confused I think - thought I could do this in jsx but now it was not working in tsx - so basically then need to declare outside the "return" section of the render method I assume of a react component

Comment: @Greg, yes, all data structures should be initialized and set up **before** so you can just plug them in when rendering the JSX. There is a very ugly and performance-destroying workaround if you desperately need it